# get_included_files() for defined path

Tags: php, function

I am trying to get the names/path of the files that are included in a files with a given path . But the get_included_files() function works only for the files in which it is written.

```
<?
    include_once('/folder1/folder2/xyz.php');
    $path = '/abcd.php';
    $includeFiles = get_included_files();
?>
```

I have tried the above code and i am getting only the included files in this file only.
I want to get the name of the included files in abcd.php i.e for the defined path.

Please HELP !!

Comment: There is a usefull [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php) about `get_included_files();`, have you read it?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
array_filter(get_included_files(), function($item) {
    return strpos($item, '/path/to/files/') === 0;                                                            
});
```